# What is the correct plural form of LEGO: LEGO or Legos?

Tags: grammatical-number, word-usage, brands

I've seen many people make reference to LEGO as Legos. E.g. "I enjoy playing with my Legos".

But from my understanding, this is incorrect and they should be referred to simply as LEGO (in capitals as per company standards). E.g. "I enjoy playing with LEGO".

There is no reference to the term Legos in any official material on LEGO's site at http://www.lego.com, although there are hundreds of mentions in LEGO's official message board (search site:lego.com +legos).

I also don't want to accept that individual pieces of a LEGO set can be referred to as Legos, as the official site refers to these as "parts". ([See here](http://us.service.lego.com/en-US/replacementparts/default.aspx).)

Also, a collection of LEGO sets can't be referred to as Legos as these are also referred to as "sets" by the LEGO company.

Is it correct to refer to LEGO in any denomination as Legos?

Comment: I can't help but snicker whenever I hear someone say "LEGOs". I don't know why, but I just find it funny. Maybe it's because it's how old people say it and has thus become a stereotype. I simply say "my LEGO".

Comment: BTW: Does Americans also pluralise similar toys like "Meccano", "Duplo", "Playmobile"  as well? Do they really say play with "Meccanos", "Duplos", "Playmobiles" (or  shortened as "Playmos")?

Comment: Yes, as a kid I played with Legos, Mechanos, Lincoln logs, HOs, Tonkas, Hot Wheels, Matchboxes, Frisbees, Jarts, Big Wheels, etc.

Comment: The example you've given is indeed incorrect - it should be "I enjoy playing **with** my Legos".

Comment: That because officially they are the pieces in my Lego sets. But in everyday speech, we just put an s there.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Owners of trademarks are free to make whatever pronouncements they like regarding how people should use their trademarks. Users of the English language, however, have the final say of how the English language works.

Just as watches made by Rolex are “Rolexes”, Apple computers are “Macs”, shoes made by Puma are “Pumas”, cars made by Audi are “Audis”, portable video games made by Nintendo are “Game Boys”, by the same process toys made by Lego are “Legos”.

“Legos” is a common usage, though not universal, and many people don’t use it especially outside North America. However, the Lego Group, paranoid (completely unreasonably) about maintaining its trademark rights, has taken a strikingly strident tone in trying to force many people to use the English language in a way that is not natural for them. At one time, the web site at legos.com had a message saying this:

> Please always refer to our products as “LEGO bricks or toys” and not “LEGOS.” By doing so, you will be helping to protect and preserve a brand of which we are very proud, and that stands for quality the world over.

Of course everyone is free to comply with these corporate demands, but the Lego Group has no authority over the English language to regulate it in this way. So if you want to feel guilty about using “Legos”, understand that the only thing you are guilty of is not obeying the demands of a Danish corporation, not for violating the rules of English grammar.

---

[Here is someone’s thesis addressing some grammatical issues with trademarks](http://www.jeffreyatw.com/static/thesis.pdf), which addresses this very issue:

> The LEGO Group is another example of a company which tries to strictly adhere to INTA's specifications, and aggressively protect its own trademarks. Its last standing LEGO patent expired in 1988 (CBC News), but despite other competitors moving in on its interlocking brick technology, trademarks can be kept forever, as long as LEGO makes sure to protect them. One almost embarrassing display of trademark anxiety is the domain http://www.legos.com. Upon visiting the domain, the visitor would receive this notice:
>
> > “The word LEGO is a brand name, and is very special to all of us in the LEGO Group Companies. We would sincerely like your help in keeping it special. Please always refer to our products as “LEGO bricks or toys” and not “LEGOS.” By doing so, you will be helping to protect and preserve a brand of which we are very proud, and that stands for quality the world over. Thank you!”
>
> The visitor would then be redirected to http://www.lego.com. While it is true that “LEGOS” is not a registered trademark (USPTO), it is ridiculous for the LEGO Group to assume that a consumer's mention of “Legos” instead of “LEGO bricks and toys” is detrimental to the brand, and even more ridiculous to impose rules like this on consumers. What might be most ridiculous of all, though, is the purchase of the domain name, if the LEGO Group is so bent on distancing itself from pluralization of its trademark.

Comment: In the American usage where Legos is plural, what is one Lego?  Does it mean a single brick, or a single set?  I'm now not sure why I've never asked anyone that question before...

Comment: One Lego would be what in the official terminology is a single “Lego brick”.

Comment: @nohat: Thankyou!  …also — I would give this +1 for the important main point that whatever manufacturers may say, people will use language however it comes most naturally.  But I’m reluctant, since parts currently read almost like a prescriptive argument for the American usage…  If you could acknowledge how the rest of us use it too, then I’d happily endorse an excellent answer :-)

Comment: I don't understand why a company wouldn't want people to use their company or product names as common nouns in plural. I always thought that when a product name became so popular that it was used as a common noun (or a verb, e.g. to *google*) it was a great achievement for the company.

Comment: @Bruno: the usual reasoning, from all I can tell, is "oh noes, our Precious® Brand™ is being watered down!" They don't want people to be hoovering with a Bosch, googling with Yahoo, or asking for a kleenex and getting a Tempo.

Comment: Once your brand name becomes common usage for a type of thing (e.g. Lego for building blocks that look like Lego, or Hoover for vacuum cleaners) then your right to trademark that name can be lost, legally.

Comment: @nohat very exhaustive reply, and even the references are interesting. +1

Comment: @nohat Good communication conveys meaning. If you're trying to make a point that involves Lego, pluralising it in a way that's odd (remember, the vast majority of communication online uses the plural Lego) will make people stop and think about this the words you're using rather than whatever the point is you're trying to make.

Comment: @mikemaccana hmm. "the vast majority of communication online uses the plural Lego" Really? [[Citation needed]]

Comment: I agree that language users, not companies, have the final say, but none of the examples you gave (Rolex, Mac, Puma, Audi and  GameBoy) are applicable because they are single items. Lego refers to a group of items (see, it's already plural) which are used together. Saying 'Legos' is pluralising a word that is already plural. You don't say 'How much woods do we need to build the shed?' or 'Do we have enough paints to cover the wall?' or 'How much sands will fit in the bucket'.  Regarding one Lego, for me a single unit of Lego is a brick or piece.

Comment: In reference to 'toys made by Lego are "Legos"',  I can't speak for others, but when I say 'Lego' I am referring to a particular object or set of objects, not a toy made by the company 'Lego'.

Comment: "Singular" and "plural" only apply to count nouns. Your use of "Lego" (like "paint" and "wood") is as a mass (or non-count) noun. Not entirely sure what your point is, though—my answer already acknowledges "many people don’t use ["Legos"] especially outside North America"

Comment: @nohat My point is that I disagree with the 'objects made by Foo are "Foos"' section of your answer when applied to 'Lego'.  But you're the only one out of the two of us who has a degree in Linguistics so I can't argue with you on technical grounds ; )  Perhaps that section of your answer could benefit from a caveat that it applies only to the US where 'Lego' is used as a countable noun.

Comment: I disagree about it being unnatural. The English language has plenty of words that are both singular and plural, such as 'fish' and 'sheep'.

Comment: Assuming that "this is the common usage" and then saying "but not outside North America" continues a common "America is the worlds voice" thinking that is mildly offensive. It is not common outside of NA and the majority of the world exists outside of that sphere.

Comment: @Doug note that I wrote "“Legos” is *a* common usage" not *the* common usage. Nevertheless, North America is home to a large majority (>70%) of native English speakers.

Comment: "Owners of trademarks are free to make whatever pronouncements they like regarding how people should use their trademarks." No they aren't! This isn't a case of them telling us what to do. It is a case of us telling them what they *must* do in order to preserve their trademark. They are only doing what we require them to do. If they don't, they will forfeit their right to their trademark. It is a matter of compliance with the regs governing trademarks.

Comment: Wouldn't the plural of "Rolex" be "Roleces"?

Comment: @PhilSweet all the silliness about how trademarks must be used only as adjectives is not part of any regulation—it is just "best practices" dreamed up by some paranoid lawyers at INTA. Nothing in trademark law *requires* any of this nonsense, nor would it be necessary to legally defend the trademark. Trademark law is about preventing competitors from using your name, not about regulating how English is used.

Comment: @Sean In Latin? Rolices. Otherwise, no, just Rolexes.

Answer (score 38):

In Danish (where the name comes from; derived from "leg godt" meaning "play good"), Norwegian, and Swedish, the name is an uncountable noun. I think it's both because it refers more to a concept than any actual piece. And also many of the pieces are small enough to be effectively "uncountable" like "grain", "sand", etc. I would personally use the word as an uncountable noun in English too. Calling it "Legos" sounds a bit odd (like saying "the Internets" etc.).

But unless you're writing advertising material and have to bother with trademarks etc., I would only capitalize the first letter, e.g.: "I enjoy playing with Lego with my nephew."

---

I just [found a page](http://www.ericharshbarger.org/lego/faq.html)  arguing that LEGO is not really a noun at all; it's an adjective. To me, this sounds right; it explains why "legos" sounds *so* wrong. It's comparable to referring to some purple bricks as "purples".

Comment: "Legos" is decidedly American, I don't think you'll ever hear a Brit saying that they played with "Legos" as a kid.  At first I thought Americans were just trying to get the British back for calling maths "math".  It is great to know that Lego is so obviously the right pronunciation when given the derivation.

Comment: Yes. Some in the UK might go to the trouble of saying "Lego bricks", but most would treat it as an uncountable noun and call it "Lego"; never "Legos".

Comment: Note that in French (yes, this is OT), Lego is used as a de facto common name and we say casually "she plays with Legos" (elle joue aux Legos). Also note that there should be an accent at Légo to provide the correct intonation in french.

Comment: That page you link to is wrong: syntactically, _LEGO_ is not an adjective, but a noun. Similarly, in Danish (and Swedish and Norwegian) is quite definitively not an adjective, ever. It is a noun and a noun alone. It just happens to be a noun that is commonly (according to the LEGO Group, exclusively) used attributively, as a noun adjunct.

Comment: @Oct: but aren't "Lego" and "Legos" pronounced identically in French? How would you tell which one a person is saying?

Comment: @sumelic In French, the word can occur in three kind of constructions. One with the numeral cardinal adjective "un", which is always singular, and will mean either a single piece of lego, or a whole model. One with the plural adjective, whether "des" or "les", which is always plural and the third one is "au", but the only usage I can think for of this is when referencing the game as the assembling game with a lot of pieces: "elle joue aux légos", hence the plural. So for me, there is no ambiguity in the usage.

Answer (score 32):

The natural English language inclination would be to call the bricks (and other pieces) "Legos", but [to trademark lawyers, trademarks are always to be used as attributive modifiers, not nouns](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emyl/languagelog/archives/000949.html). For this reason, the Lego company produced a famous warning not just on their web site, but long before the web existed. It was printed on the little catalogs that came in our sets:

[image: Susan Williams note from 1985 catalog]

The note said:

> ***Dear Parents and Children***
>
> LEGO® is a brand name that is very special to all of us in the LEGO Group Companies. We would sincerely appreciate your help in keeping it special by referring to our bricks as "LEGO Bricks or Toys" and not just "LEGOS". By doing so, you will be helping to protect and preserve a brand name that stands for quality the world over.
>
> If at any time we can be of service to you regarding our products, please feel free to write to us.
>
> *Susan Williams*

Similar messages appeared in [catalogs from 1979 to 1986](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/563/146).

"Susan Williams" was a fiction, the personification of the Customer Affairs department — but, as if she were Santa Claus, in those days the Lego company always acted if she were very much real. If you wrote a letter to Lego and got a response, "she" signed it (see [this example of a Susan Williams letter](http://laura.gjovaag.com/lego/pics/letterone.jpg)). So, it was a *personal* request. And it was a request from a person representing a company we all loved, because we loved their product.

So, when the sort of enthusiastic children who loved Lego so much that they read the fine print of the catalog and wrote letters to the company, we took the admonishment very seriously — but, I think, generally missed the point. Not being trademark lawyers, the message didn't read as "call them bricks or toys, not lego" — it was "*don't call them legos!*" So, we grew up with that warning in our minds, carefully playing with *lego* even as we casually blew our noses on kleenexes and tossed our unwanted xeroxes in dumpsters.

For *this* reason, the Lego vs. Legos debate has become a sort of shibboleth for the fan community. It's a signifier that the person you're talking to either grew up as one of those geeky fans, or is tied into the loose network of builders, makers, and artists for whom Lego is a passion. **In many ways the technical correctness (or hyper-correctness) isn't as important as this cultural implication.**

Comment: The [post by Geoff Pullum](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emyl/languagelog/archives/000943.html) that is linked to on the article linked to in your answer is a great read that very succinctly debunks this whole ‘trademarks are adjectives’ madness. (Hint: trademarks are **not** adjectives. Ever. In any way. Under any circumstances.)

Comment: @Janus Since this is by definition an English-language nitpicking site, I will concede that point. :)

Answer (score 14):

Since the owner of the name chooses always to use “LEGO”, then it is not strictly correct to call the toy anything else.  But I doubt the company’s brand protection lawyers are going to start serving cease-and-desist orders on children calling the building blocks “Legos”.

I think “Legos” is predominantly an American English thing.  As youngsters in the UK my friends and I always referred to it as “Lego”.

As for writing the name in all-caps: while that is clearly the manufacturer’s preference, it could appear to stand out as unusual emphasis in casual writing.

Comment: Interesting for you to mention US English as I am in Australia and from memory my friends always referred to it as just Lego. So maybe it is a US thing.

Comment: This is definitely an American English thing.  In my experience - I've discussed this with quite a few friends on both sides of the pond - it's pretty consistently called *Lego* in the UK and Australia, and *Legos* in the US.  Not sure about Canada.

Comment: @PLL: In the US, *Legos* is a noun and *Lego* is an adjective.

Comment: @Jon: absolutely, yes — good clarification, I’d only been thinking of the nouns.

Comment: @PLL: On second thought, "a Lego" is a single Lego brick. Argh.

Comment: Remind me not to play with lego in the US, I think I would hit someone (with a particularly big lego brick) if they used *legos* around me.

Comment: Just checked with my nearest native Canadian (my own usage might be affected by my UK childhood) and he thinks Legos sounds silly. He would say "a lot of Lego" or "playing with Lego" and if forced into pluralization would rather say "100 Lego bricks" than "100 Legos". I didn't offer a choice, he volunteered the brick usage. He feels his cohort all use the word like that, though they have heard Legos. Apparently there's a video mocking George Bush that refers to him playing with Legos.

Answer (score 7):

its the same as 'wood'. plural form is not 'woods'. You do not have planks of woods, you have planks of wood. I have a piece of wood, not i have woods. I have a piece of LEGO, not I have legos

Comment: And your reference for your assertion that it is the same as "wood"? (From the other answers, it would appear that non-US speakers generally agree with you and US speakers generally don't, so I am asking what is your authority for making such a bold assertion).

Comment: So you think of "lego" as an uncountable substance of which all legos are merely representatives? That can't be right: the substance legos are made out of is plastic, not lego. You're surely really trying to say something closer to "fish" or "sand".

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue here is the issue of plurality.  Lego is the same in plural form as it is in singular.

> *"a piece of lego"*
>
> *"pieces of lego"*

I would argue the word has moved from a proper noun to a general noun, so long has it been in the language; hence my use of it in lowercase.  The representation of it in allcaps, is a marketing device of the company, for trademark usage, they do not use it themselves within most text, so I do not believe it to be necessary (particularly as that usually indicates an acronym, which it is not).  If keeping it as a proper noun, then it should be initial caps.

Comment: Where are you familiar with this usage from?  In the US, it’s definitely typically inflected in the plural, as *legos*;  in the UK, at least for me and my friends, *lego* definitely functioned as a mass noun, not as an uninflected plural: “Have you still got your lego?”  “No, my parents gave it away when I went to uni.”  rather than “*No, my parents gave them away…”

Comment: @PLL: Well I typically only ever speak for British English, and will explicitly state if straying in to American.  In the UK, *legos* would definitely be viewed as wrong.  You are right on the mass noun part.

Comment: Agreed that *legos* is definitely wrong in the UK; what I meant was that in my experience, so is treating *lego* as plural. I would never say/expect “?Your lego are all over the floor,” only “Your lego is all over the floor.”  But you would use the former of those, or at least find it acceptable?  (FWIW, I was brought up — at least at peak lego-playing ages — mostly in London \[reading your comment [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/what-does-the-british-idiom-taking-the-piss-mean/10776#10776), I’ll clarify: Queens Park\]; perhaps this is regional difference?)

Comment: The company insists that LEGO is not a noun at all. In [their company profile](http://cache.lego.com/downloads/aboutus/LEGO_company_profile_UK.pdf) the go so far as to say "It should always be accompanied by a noun. For example, LEGO set, LEGO products, LEGO Group".

Comment: @Dsve: Yes, they fight hard to keep it as a trademark and not a standard word, thus they always want it to be a pronoun, and a mark of ownership on any other noun describing the products.

Comment: I say Lego's and write Lego's.  The apostrophe is standing in for "brand brick" and it's never failed me.

Comment: @BrucetheHoon You must not have talked to many Brits. From this thread, some seem very hung up on the idea indeed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct to refer to LEGO in any denomination as Legos?

Technically, no. However, this didn't stop people from referring to Band-Aid bandages as bandaids. The brand name LEGO could be in the process of being genericized.

Comment: I think the conversion of brand names into nouns is very much an American thing. You dont buy a box of tissues, you guys buy Kleenex :-) This has not happened much in other English-speaking countries.

Comment: @Eno Bullocks. ;) I find that hard to believe. Probably the very first trademarked words to become generic, *linoleum*, was invented by an Englishman. The word *sellotape* is used instead of *Scotch Tape* (adhesive tape) in England, Ireland, Australia and many other countries. *Hoover* is still a trademark in the US, but is now generic in the UK…

Comment: But those are exceptions rather than the rule in the UK. Its more commonly the other way around in the US (I am an Englishman but I have lived in the US for 20 years now).

Comment: BTW, an Englishman would say "Bollocks" rather than "Bullocks" :-)

Comment: They were being polite. ; )

Comment: @ghoppe - Here in Australia (or at least in my part of Australia) we usually say "sticky tape".