# Correct punctuation in numbers with mixed numbers and words like "2 thousand"

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, numbers

What is the correct punctuation when writing a mix of numbers and words, when writing a big number?

I'm especially not clear about the hyphens or spaces. Is it for example:

> 2-thousand euro

or

> 2 thousand euro

As far as I could find, when writing it *all in words* there is a space and no hyphen:

> two thousand euro

Is the mixed-case the same?

Comment: I think you are *overthinking* as it doesn't actually matter. But anyways a good question. I think this [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/33381/186126)  may help you.

Comment: No punctuation, and you need to pluralize *euro*.

Comment: Write Out Numbers Using Words: https://www.thebalance.com/write-numbers-using-words-4083198

Comment: @Mick If you mean the "s" on "euros", both with and without seem fine: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13551/%E2%82%AC10-ten-euro-or-ten-euros

Comment: @Steeven Ah! Another reason for Brexit. ;-)

Comment: The fact that you haven't pluralised ***euro*** implies that you're asking about an [**attributive noun**](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Attributive-Noun.htm) usage, as in ***a two-thousand-euro handbag***. In such contexts it's stylistically clumsy to mix figures and words for the "number" component, but you could reasonably write ***a 2000-euro handbag*** or [***a 400 pound gorilla***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+400+pound+gorilla%22). All elements within an attributive noun are normally linked by hyphens, but not *always*.

Answer (score -2):

My English teacher in school told me to never mix numbers and words together.

But I do it allot in marketing and use capitols like this.

> 2 Thousand Euros.

This is more of an art than a science and if I was to commit heresy by including a number in a block of text in a story it would be like this.

> I went to the gallery today and saw a lovely old painting. The man
>   wanted 2 thousand euros for it, but I was 3 hundred euros short.

Comment: Too bad you didn't listen.

Comment: Yes, I was busy reading.

Comment: Too bad you did not read enough to learn how to spell.

Comment: Yes they didn't accept me to Hogwarts.