# How do you say 100ths of the euro? cents/ centimes

Tags: money

Does it depend one he country how to say amounts in euros?

25.90
 twenty-five euro(s), ninety cents
 twenty-five euro(s), ninety centimes
 twenty-five euro(s), ninety

and with no euro, 
 .70
   seventy cents/ euro cents?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: It depends on the language (rather than the country.) In English, a euro is divided in 100 cents. In French, they are _centimes_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not just about the English language.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth to the extent that the question is about how a native English speaker expresses a common reference, I would say that it is solely about  the English Language.

Answer (score 3):

### *Cent* vs. *Centime* vs. *Eurocents*

The actual coins say *cent*, not *centime*:

[image: Coins from "1 cent" to "2 euro", showing old and new designs]
Image source: [Euro coin designs](http://www.websideof.com/euro-coin-designs/)

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centime#Subdivision_of_euro:_cent_or_centime.3F), *centime* is only preferred in French-speaking countries:

> In the European community cent is the official name for one hundredth of a euro. However, in French-speaking countries the word centime is the preferred term. Indeed, the Superior Council of the French language of Belgium recommended in 2001 the use of centime, since cent is also the French word for "hundred". An analogous decision was published in the *Journal officiel* in France (December 2, 1997).

The term [*euro cent*](http://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Eurocents) (sometimes spelled as one word or with initial capital) is also used in English.

### Euro vs. Euros

See [€10 = "ten euro" or "ten euros"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/13551/191178). In actual usage both terms are used.