# What do you call the type of impoliteness where a person you know enters your house uninvited?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, slang, colloquialisms

Say a person (e.g. your brother-in-law) who enters your house without being invited, opens your fridge without asking, etc. How do you describe that? Not just "impolite" of course, something more specific and informal.

Comment: Trespasser....?

Comment: 'House' - The character in House MD TV show. You are describing him .

Comment: ^ +1 for a reference to the greatest medical drama ever :').

Comment: I met a guy in college that basically talked at me, followed me home talking, more or less invited himself in, and then later would simply walk into my apartment without knocking.  At which point I figured I should learn his name at least.  And have a discussion about knocking.

Comment: Lock your door.

Comment: @MooingDuck - was that guy's name [**Cosmo Kramer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmo_Kramer) by any chance?

Comment: I’d have a word for your brother-in-law, but I think Stack Overflow’s profanity filter would stop me posting it.

Comment: "Without so much as a by-your-leave"?

Comment: @Vector Or Joey Tribbiani :p

Answer (score 57):

> [**overfamiliar**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overfamiliar)
>   [Farlex] - taking undue liberties

and

> b. Unduly forward or brash; offensively presumptuous: She displayed an
>   overfamiliar attitude toward her superiors. [AHDEL]

Comment: While technically accurate, in my opinion this word comes across as much more formal than *presumptuous*. While sounding great in writing, I wouldn't tell someone that they're "being overfamiliar"; I would say that they're "being presumptuous." I've never heard this word used verbally in place of *presumptuous*. Granted, the OP didn't specify how or where the term would be used.

Answer (score 47):

In the given example, I would find both the behaviour, and the person committing it, to be ***[presumptuous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/presumptuous?q=presumptuous)***:

> (Of a person or their behaviour) failing to observe the limits of what is permitted or appropriate

However, this could sound somewhat reserved, and definitely doesn't have any bite. As the question is a request for something specific and informal, my reflexive response to somebody taking it upon themselves to start rifling through my fridge would be that they're ***[taking the piss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taking_the_piss)***:

> to take liberties at the expense of others, or to be unreasonable.

There is [a nice question regarding this idiom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/what-does-the-british-idiom-taking-the-piss-mean/) on English.StackExchange, with user @Orbling providing [a splendid explanation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/10776/69536) of phrase's meaning in the context we're dealing with here.

This is a British (and I think Australian) idiom, so I don't know if Americans and other English speakers would understand the meaning. It is vulgar, so if it's your priest or solicitor who is scoffing your Dairylea Triangles, you might not want to resort to this; however it's not overly rude, and could certainly be used amongst friends, family and even colleagues with whom you have a good relationship.

Having said that, somebody who marches into your house and begins helping themselves to your food really *is* taking the piss, so I personally wouldn't be too worried about offending such a misanthropic slob.

Comment: I don't know if this varies widely, but I live in the south of England and "taking the piss" is closer in meaning to mocking or making fun of. At the harsh end it can be a form of bullying, and at the light end it's mere teasing. I've never heard the phrase being used in the context you described.

Comment: @LeoKing I grew up and still live in London, and here 'taking the piss' can either have the definition you've given, or the one alluded to in my answer: taking advantage of hospitality, exploiting generosity, or otherwise not contributing your fair share. I'd be interested to know whether this second definition exists elsewhere in the UK and other territories where 'take the piss' is a recognised expression!

Comment: @LeoKing That usage is more common, but there's also the (related) one that 586ml refers to: something or someone that is so unreasonable it's almost a joke. "My postman used to wake me up at 8 a.m., then he started coming at 6 - now it's half four! It's just taking the piss, really, isn't it?"

Comment: @starsplusplus I think you're at the crux of this 'second' definition: it's a behaviour so far in excess of what's acceptable that it implies a disregard and disrespect akin to ridicule.

Comment: @568ml That's a good way of putting it.

Comment: I always read the usage you just described in line with the first definition, as if it was saying "My postman used to wake me up at 8 a.m., then he started coming at 6 - now it's half four! He's making fun of me, isn't he?" Something like that. Anyway, it's good to know - I've only visited London and never for a great length of time, so I've never noticed much idiolect. :)

Comment: "Taking the piss" wouldn't be widely understood in the US.

Answer (score 13):

In British English I'd say:

- He's got a (lot of) nerve, helping himself like that.

[**A lot of nerve**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/nerve)

> 1. Fig. great rudeness; a lot of audacity or brashness. (*Typically: have ~; take ~.)
>
> *He walked out on her, and that took a lot of nerve!*
>
> *You have a lot of nerve! You took my parking place!*
>
> **What (a) nerve!** and **Of all the nerve!**
>
> Inf. How rude!
>    - *Bob: Lady, get the devil out of my way! Mary: What a
>   nerve!
>
>      - Jane: You can't have that one! I saw it first! Sue: Of all the
>   nerve! I can too have it!*

**[Cheek](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cheek)**

> Impertinent boldness: had the cheek to insult his hosts
>   (U.S. informal) *I'm amazed they have the cheek to ask in the first place*

- He's got a cheek coming to my home without being invited.

Other *informal* synonyms are:

- [gall](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gall)
- [chutzpah](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chutzpah)
- [brass neck](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brass+neck)

Comment: +1 for Cheek. Though I think it's always better to say "cheeky".

Comment: I've never heard *a cheek* (with this meaning of *cheek*). I'd just say, "He's got cheek...". *the cheek* or *cheek*, never *a cheek*

Comment: "a lot of nerve" is common in American English, too.

Comment: I've heard "cheeky bastard" in American English, but not "cheek" alone

Comment: First example of "a lot of nerve" is a different meaning than "rudeness", more "bravery".

Comment: @James if you think about it, a person who presents himself at your door without previously calling, opens your fridge and helps himself to your food, switches on your telly or changes the channel you are watching requires a type of arrogant courage, as in *how dare he?!* or *does he really think he can get away with this?!* In the first example, if the wife is exemplary and has no obvious fault, then yes, the husband who walks out on her (especially if children are involved in the abandonment) "has a lot of nerve"= effrontery/audacity. You could also call him shameless.

Comment: @Mari-Lou Oddly enough I read that example backwards, something like "She finally removed herself and her kids from that abusive relationship.  That took a lot of nerve".  It works, and it doesn't mean shameless, which is kind of strange as all I did was reverse the genders.

Comment: +1 for *chutzpah*! The *Etymology* section of its [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chutzpah) is quite informative.

Answer (score 8):

His behaviour can also be  described as *intrusive*.

Comment: Behaviour, while a perfectly fine spelling, is the British version of the American, also perfectly fine, behavior.

Comment: You might rather want to say 'behavior' is an American version of the Brisish English word, not the other way around. English comes from Britain, of course. Not to mention this is entirely off-topic ;)

Answer (score 4):

*Ill-mannered* or *impudent* can be used to describe this attitude.

Behaving boldly, with contempt or disregard for propriety in behavior toward others; unblushingly forward; impertinent; saucy.

Answer (score 4):

That's :-

1. feeling entitled

or

1. taking liberties

Answer (score 3):

*Impolite,* boorish, disrespectful, rude, discourteous, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Now, that's just ***disrespectful!***

Or, just plain ***inconsiderate!***

Answer (score 1):

Also *arrogant / arrogance* and *high-handed / high-handedness*.

Comment: Arrogant sounds a bit too harsh to express this idea

Answer (score 0):

Your brother-in-law is inurbane.

**Inurbanity**:      Lack of urbanity or courtesy; unpolished manners or deportment; inurbaneness; rudeness. --Bp. Hall. [1913 Webster]

Answer (score 0):

Excessively laid back.

I'd also use 'nerve' and 'cheek' as already suggested by Mari-Lou-A

Answer (score 0):

***Rude*** can work, IMO. ***Nervy*** might be even better:

> brashly presumptuous or insolent.

Answer (score 0):

*[Discourteous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discourteous)* seems appropriate.

> rude or impolite : not showing good manners
>
> showing rudeness and a lack of consideration for other people.

You could also consider *[insolent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/insolent)*, though that may be harsher than necessary in my opinion.

> boldly rude or disrespectful; contemptuously impertinent; insulting

*Rude*, *ill-mannered*, or just plain *impolite* should also suffice.

In Chinese culture, we normally describe people exhibiting this behavior as 没家教, which roughly translates to *poor family upbringing*, and reflects badly on the individual's parents.